# How to read multiple directories from a folder and save it as the same name

Tags: r, for-loop, naming

I am trying to read different directories from a folder into this code and then have corresponding output names. The input is "datadir =" and the output name is "studyname ="

Example 1:

```
library(GGIR)

g.shell.GGIR(mode = 1:5, 
  datadir = "/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/raw_geneactive/800-0216-F1_left wrist_060384_2022-04-13 11-34-43.bin", 
  outputdir = "/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/night/ggir_results_night", 
  studyname= "800-0216-F1_night",
  f0=1,f1=0, do.report=c(2,3,4,5),overwrite=FALSE,visualreport=TRUE,
  viewingwindow=2)
```

Example 2

```
library(GGIR)

g.shell.GGIR(mode = 1:5, 
  datadir = "/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/raw_geneactive/800-0111-198_left wrist_060354_2022-04-13 10-02-55.bin", 
  outputdir = "/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/night/ggir_results_night", 
  studyname= "800-0111-198_night",
  f0=1,f1=0, do.report=c(2,3,4,5),overwrite=FALSE,visualreport=TRUE,
  viewingwindow=2)
```

I tried to just call the file from the general "raw_geneactive" folder and the code will not run. I really haven't had a lot of experience with for-loops.

I tried this which may work logically to call in the files but do not how to deal with these .bin files and do not know how to make the study name match the file name.

```
setwd("~/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/raw_geneactive/")

listbin<- dir(pattern = "*.bin") # creates the list of all the cs files in the directory
for (k in 1:length(listbin)){
  ldf[[k]] <- readBin(listbin[k])
  outputdir = "/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/night/ggir_results_night",
  studyname= "%",
  f0=1,f1=0, do.report=c(2,3,4,5),overwrite=FALSE,visualreport=TRUE,
  viewingwindow=2)
```

Comment: Hi. What do you want the result to look like? E.g. do you want a vector/list of file names and the study names extracted from them? Or do you want to modify the file names in place, or re-organise the files in some way?

Comment: I want a vector/list of file names and the study names extracted from the first portion

Comment: if you found the answer below helpful, can you please mark it as correct so that others know that it's the solution to this problem? If the answer wasn't helpful, please add a comment to the answer explaining why so that people can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed answer is nearly there, but using loops in R to iterate over every element of a vector often makes code more complicated than it needs to be. Instead you can use `lapply()` to apply the same function (in this case, `str_extract` from the [`stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org) package) to every file name returned by `dir()` to extract the study names.

I've commented this code quite heavily just in case you're not already familiar with `lapply()`.

```r
lapply(
  # The first argument is the data to apply the function to
  setNames(nm = dir("~/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/raw_geneactive/", pattern = ".bin")),
  # The second argument is the name of the function to apply
  stringr::str_extract,
  # Any further arguments are passed onto `str_extract()` to control how it 
  # operates – in this case we need to specify the pattern to extract from the 
  # file names
  pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9-]"
)
```

Note that I've wrapped the result of `dir()` in `setNames()`, which sets the name of each element in the vector of file names to be the file name itself. This is then preserved by `lapply()`, meaning the end product is named list of study names, where the name of each element is the file name and the value is the study name.

If you're new to `lapply()`, you might find it useful to look at the `map()` family of functions in the [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org) package, which act in a similar way to `lapply()` but give you more control ([and more consistency](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/bk01_base-functions.html)) over the result. For example, `map_chr()` always returns a character vector, `map_dfr()` returns a data frame, etc.

```r
purrr::map_chr(
  # The first argument is the data to apply the function to
  setNames(nm = dir("~/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/raw_geneactive/", pattern = ".bin")),
  # The second argument is the name of the function to apply
  stringr::str_extract,
  # Any further arguments are passed onto `str_extract()`
  pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9-]"
)
```

Note that if you didn't need to preserve the file names, you could make the code even simpler because `str_extract()` is a *vectorised* function, meaning that if you give it a vector of inputs then it will apply itself to each one in turn:

```r
library(stringr)

str_extract(
  dir("~/Users/katefreeman/Sync/ForbowShared/SleepData/raw_geneactive/", pattern = ".bin")),
  pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9-]"
)
```

However, `str_extract()` on its own doesn't preserve the names, so we just end up with a vector of study names without the file names.